# Display the wave form of the playing media file in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

While playing a sound file in silverlight, I'd like to display the wave form (or get an amplitude value at least) of the output. Is there a standard way to do this?

EDIT: Is this possible in SL3? Or SL4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use: http://salusemediakit.codeplex.com/